ActiveMQ old messages are not getting consumed
I am using ActiveMq Artemis. Messages are consumed from a Springboot @JmsListener. Sometimes the queue is starting to grow from 0 to 2500 records. Then still the consumer is processing the items from the queue. But some items in the queue stay longer and get stuck there for like hours, but during that time, new messages in the queue get processed. All the messages have same configuration (like same priority). So I wonder why FIFO is not working in the queue?
These are queue attributes:
Attribute   Value
Acknowledge attempts    1988315
Address my.stream.queue
Auto delete false
Configuration managed   false
Consumer count  1
Consumers before dispatch   0
Dead letter address DLA
Delay before dispatch   -1
Delivering count    68
Delivering size 706588
Durable true
Durable delivering count    68
Durable delivering size 706588
Durable message count   2412
Durable persistent size 28441174
Durable scheduled count 1
Durable scheduled size  5589
Enabled true
Exclusive   false
Expiry address  ExpiryQueue
Filter  
First message age   5400
First message as json   [{"JMSType":"TEXT","address":"my.stream.queue","_type":"java.lang.String","messageID":17208908385,"type":3,"priority":4,"userID":"ID:2c04dc5c-0787-11ef-aa81-0242ac110002","durable":true,"__AMQ_CID":"myApi-5a88e9d9ee344a60a6ac52c6e51ccca5","_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY":1714546266227,"_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE":1,"expiration":0,"timestamp":1714546261227}]
First message timestamp 1714546261227
Group buckets   -1
Group count 0
Group first key 
Group rebalance false
Group rebalance pause dispatch  false
Id  4492642
Last value  false
Last value key  
Max consumers   -1
Message count   2412
Messages acknowledged   1954550
Messages added  1964674
Messages expired    0
Messages killed 7712
Name    my.stream.queue
Object Name org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="my.stream.queue",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="anycast",queue="my.stream.queue"
Paused  false
Persistent size 28441174
Prepared transaction message count  0
Purge on no consumers   false
Retroactive resource    false
Ring size   -1
Routing type    ANYCAST
Scheduled count 1
Scheduled size  5589
Temporary   false
User    xxx@xx.com

